# Why do only some of the Kaioshins & Gods of Destruction get erased with their universe?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Episode 122, the bleachers are shrunk and we can see all the remaining Kaioshins, angels, and participants.  Looking at ~5:43, I see many more than 2 remaining Kaioshin and their Gods of Destruction.  There is a total of 6 sets, and 2 universes are left in the tournament.  I thought that when a universe got erased, the Kaioshin and the God of Destruction went with it.

[image]

Why are there so many left in the bleachers?

*I thought about marking the pic as a spoiler, but anyone who has watched enough Dragon Ball knew that it would end up at this point.*

Answer (score 3):

Out of the entire Dragon Ball multiverse, only 8 universes were marked for destruction by both Zenos due to failing to maintain or exceed an adequate quality of life, otherwise known as their 'mortal level.' The 4 sets of Kaioshin & Gods of Destruction circled in the photo (circle the fox, not the clown) are exempt from participating in the Zenos' twisted game of survival because they have met or exceeded the minimum mortal level required to continue existing in peace. The only ones participating are Universe 7, represented by Beerus the cat and company, and Universe 11, represented by Belmod the clown and company.

Answer (score 1):

The Tournament of Power was for those Universes whose mortal level was too low. They are :-

1. Universe 9
2. Universe 10
3. Universe 2
4. Universe 6
5. Universe 4
6. Universe 3
7. Universe 7
8. Universe 11

The other Universes are exempt from the Tournament of Power.

Here is the wikia article for the [Tournament of Power](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Tournament_of_Power)

Answer (score 1):

There is a quantified value called as *The Mortal Value* which Zeno and the Grand priest use to rank the twelve universes based on the quality of mortals existing in that particular Universe. The Mortal level of a universe is linked to the job of the Supreme Kai and God of destruction. Universe 1, 12, 5 and 8 and have a very high value with regard to this and hence were exempted from entering into the tournament of power! Hence, the Supreme Kais and Gods of destructions you see sitting there are the Gods of these Universes. Out of the 8th competing Universes, 6 gods of destructions and supreme kais along with their respective universes have been erased as of episode 127.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by this since i started watching the tournament later on. From Eps 102+ so i didnt know all the gods but I didnt know the other universes were invited to watch. 
Also, I dont see Toppo in this picture maybe the shot was taken eps. 126 or -